# Get rid of the need for confirmation when a user registers

Tags: joomla-2.5, virtuemart, registration

I'd like to stop the need for an account to be confirmed when a user registers to be gone. On our client's website a user shouldn't need to go through the confirmation process once they've registered - they should be able to place orders immediately after they've registered without confirmation.

I have seen that you can enable non-registered users to checkout. But I would still like to get rid of the confirmation process.

Does this make sense? Anyone know how? Thanks.

Comment: Are you usings Joomla's default registration component?

Comment: I think so, I haven't changed it. Whats it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to the following in the Joomla backend:

**Users** >> **User Manager** >> **Options**

Then set the **New User Account Activation** parameter to **None**.

This will disable new users having to manually activate their accounts upon registration.

Comment: Glad it helped :)